# How to use these xml parameters in HttpWebrequest

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Hi I would like to pass some values to my HttpWebRequest. I have a PHP code where some guy has passed parameters like this to his CURL Request.

```
$postForApps = '<?xml version="1.0"?><request><appinfo><authkey>'.$authkey.'</authkey><appkey>'.$appkey.'</appkey><appname>'.$appName.'</appname></appinfo> <requestdetails> <action>authenticate</action><callback>'.$appCallbackURL.'</callback></requestdetails></request>';
```

I would like to know how to pass this kind of parameters to my asp .net application.